# Typing function for resetting zustand stores

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, zustand

I have zustand stores created using Car ID, and I needed the function to easily reset these stores (dozens at once). I was looking through the web for possible solutions and found one, but its very hard for me to type it, here is the function itself:

```
const resetSet = new Set();
export const resettable = (create: any) => (initialState: any) => {
  const useStore = create(() => initialState);
  const reset = () => useStore.setState(initialState, true);
  resetSet.add(reset);
  return useStore;
};
export const resetAll = () => resetSet.forEach((reset: any) => reset());
```

And the example usage:

```
export type CarsState = {
  carInfo: CarInfoType | null;
  setCarInfo: (carInfo: CarInfoType | null) => void;
...etc.
}

  export const useCarState = (carID: string) =>
  resettable(
    create<CarState>()(
      persist(immer(handler), {
        name: `carState-${carID}`,
        storage: createJSONStorage(() => sessionStorage),
      }),
    ),
  );
```

I tried several things, but for example here I cannot type useStore hook arguments properly:

```
import { StateCreator } from 'zustand';

type CreateFunction = <StateType>(initializer: () => StateType) => StateCreator<StateType>;

type ResettableFunction = <T>(create: CreateFunction) => (initialState: T) => StateCreator<T>;

const resetSet = new Set<() => void>();

export const resettable: ResettableFunction = <T>(create: CreateFunction) => (initialState: T) => {
  const useStore = create(() => initialState);
  const reset = () => useStore(initialState, true);
  resetSet.add(reset);
  return useStore;
};
```